# setting elements in flow layout panel side by side in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, flowlayoutpanel

Good Afternoon. I am practicing c# on my own.I am developing a countdown timer dynamically. To display time in 00:00:00 format i'm using FlowLayoutPanel and labels , and set panel property "FlowDirection" to LefttoRight. The problem is, output is displaying like
00:00:00 in topdown manner(like 00 in first row, : in second row,00 in third row ,: in fourth row,00 in fifth row) but i want them to place side by side.
Do i need to add another property or go with another panel(if so, please suggest me one).
Thank you.

Comment: I tried this but it works fine to me.

Comment: @tarzanbappa, sir, if i develop using design it is working, but when i try to develop programmatically, it is displaying like topdown manner. Thank you for Trying to help me.

Comment: So please put your code here.Otherwise we can't identify what is the problem.

Comment: Are you using 1 or 5 labels? A  FlowLayoutPanel can only layout controls, not their contents. Do you set their width? Have you turned Autosize off? Do they have enough space for a horizontal layout?

Comment: @tarzanbappa, I got it sir. By using these two FlowLayoutPanel properties     AutoSize = true;
               AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly; My sincere thanks to you sir.

Comment: @TaW, your suggestion helps me so much. Thank you.